# why my Update table function doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I know I am going get sticks from you guys for using `mysql_**` but I have to at the moment as I am far into the project and I cannot go back and start again. So please be gentle.

Anyway, I don't understand why my update table doesn't work!!

This is the code:

```
    <?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="mydetails"; // Mysql username
$password="XXXXXXX"; // Mysql password
$db_name="mydetails"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $tbl_name SET balance='$balance' WHERE id='$id'");


// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "The user has been banned successfully!";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='suspend_users.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

If I remove the `$balance` and leave `''` empty or replace `$balance` with a text or number, it will enter it the balance column which means it does work and connects successfully to the database without any issue. But when I say `balance='$balance'` it doesn't work at all.

I do have a input field with `id="balance"` and `name="balance"` as well so that is not missing.

Can someone please help me out with this without giving me a griff for using `mysql_*`?

Thanks

**Update:**

my form code:

```
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['username']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['balance']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="balance" type="text" id="balance" value="<? echo $rows['balance']; ?>" size="15"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">Ban and Remove</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `$balance` supposed to be?

Comment: you have not declared $balance, what is $balance here?

Comment: $balance is not assigned with any value

Comment: In addition, balance is almost certainly numeric (unless you're a raving lunatic, of course), you would be advised to get rid of the quote marks around it.

Comment: use an appropriate value of $balance and tell me whats the result
`UPDATE $tbl_name SET balance=3434 WHERE id='$id'`

Comment: you say: `input field called (id, class) balance`.. you need to set the `name` of the input field to `balance`, then get it with `$balance = $_GET['balance']`.

Comment: No any value set for $balance.!

Comment: the $balance is an input field id="balance" in my form. I've updated my post with the form code.

Comment: So why don't you use `$balance = $_GET['balance']`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills, i need to update the database but i think your way I get the details from database!!!

Comment: @user2056633 `$_GET` holds the get variables of the URL. In this case, the data from the form, NOT from the database.

Comment: Please follow as per @ExplosionPills

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE ". $tbl_name ." SET balance='".$balance."' WHERE id='".$id."'");
```

Comment: Even if it were right (I have no idea), a little more "meat" on the answer would be nice. You're not Moses bringing down the tablets - _explain_ your answers.

Comment: i've tried that and i got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

Comment: the statement you are proposing is the same as the `UPDATE` statement above.

Comment: yah its same but added concatenating to it.

Comment: @DipeshParmar, yes, saw that. it was my bad. i meant to say its name is balance. i've updated my questions with the form code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The values of form cannot be accessed using variable names they are stored in global arrays $_GET or $_POST (depends which method you use in form). You may try this:

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

//get value of balance. i am supposing you have used get method in your form
$balance = $_GET['balance'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $tbl_name SET balance='$balance' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Answer (score -1):

just put `$tbl_name` in quotes like this `'$tbl_name'`

Comment: ideally it should work. don't know who put my answer in negative!! i have executed more than 1K queries like this. Do one thing try to echo your update statement. i guess balance variable must be having some problem

Comment: -1 This is not his issue, and does not fix his problem. It's valid, but not a fix.

Comment: @ScoRpion... Is this one of his issues? `UPDATE TABLE members SET...` and `UPDATE TABLE 'members' SET...` will do exactly the same in this case.

Comment: @MiniGod but $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE $tbl_name SET balance='$balance' WHERE id='$id'");. and when you will print this it will display like this UPDATE members SET balance='$balance' WHERE id='$id' rather values of $balance and Id

Comment: that is happening because of mysql_query remove this and then try to print

Comment: @ScoRpion... I believe you're the one being confused about double and single quotes...

Comment: @MiniGod, the thing is it hasn't. because I've tried all the methods mentioned above and still doesn't work. I've tried your $balance = $_POST['balance'] method as well and didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

`$balance` is never set in your code.

Try adding `$balance = $_POST['balance']`,

Or if the form has `method="get"` use `$balance = $_GET['balance']`.

Comment: MiniGod, i'm not trying to see whats in the balance column though!! i just need to update the blanace column.

Comment: `$_POST` and `$_GET` are from the form, not the database.

Comment: yes, i understand. but i think you misundrestood what i am trying to do. I have a form as you can see with an input named balance. i need to UPDATE the balance column in the database with the number/value that I enter in the balance input field.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, you take the value of the `$_POST['balance']`, which comes from the the input in the form, and send it to the database using `UPDATE TABLE`. Try it!